# Why load staticfiles for every template even if it is extended?

Tags: python, django, static, django-templates

I have a **base.html** file which has some *'random' html* code and I have the following code:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      ... 
     {% block extra_js_top %}{% endblock %}
   </head>
   ...
</html>
```

In my **index.html** file I extend **base.html** and I load some *extra javascript* files:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
...
{% block extra_js_top %}
   <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "js/somejs.js" %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

The problem is that extra javascript doesn't load because of the static var. It doesn't load even if I extend **base.html** which have the `{% load staticfiles %}` inside the template. Finally I solved the problem adding one more `{% load staticfiles %}` at **index.html**.

My question is why we should add `{% load staticfiles %}` for every template we use even if we extend a file that has it already?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As per Django's latest [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/language/#custom-libraries-and-template-inheritance), this is done *for the sake of maintainability and sanity*

> When you load a custom tag or filter library, the tags/filters are
> only made available to the current template – not any parent or child
> templates along the template-inheritance path.
>
> For example, if a template foo.html has {% load humanize %}, a child
> template (e.g., one that has {% extends "foo.html" %}) will not have
> access to the humanize template tags and filters. The child template
> is responsible for its own {% load humanize %}.
>
> This is a feature for the sake of maintainability and sanity.

Answer (score 3):

Because that's the way template tags work. You need to load each library for every template file that uses them.

Comment: But I extend a template that include the load. Wouldn't be better if a full inheritance worked instead of loading library in each template?

Answer (score 0):

It's logical that you'll need `{% load staticfiles %}` wherever you want url expansion to occur. If you have that happening in both `base.html` & `index.html`, you'll have to include it at both places (as you've already figured).