# How to use django-bootstrap3

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a django website, and now I want to use bootstrap. 
I found django-bootstrap3: [django-bootstrap3](http://django-bootstrap3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html)

First I installed the package over pycharm.
Like in quickstart, I can load:

```
{# Load the tag library #}
{% load bootstrap3 %}

{# Load CSS and JavaScript #}
{% bootstrap_css %}
{% bootstrap_javascript %}

{# Display django.contrib.messages as Bootstrap alerts #}
{% bootstrap_messages %}
```

But for

```
{% bootstrap_form form %}
```

I get an error:

> Invalid block tag on line 22: 'bootstrap_form', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

how to fix this error?

PS: I have added bootstrap3 to Installed_Apps in my settings.py

Comment: Put all your code until the line 22

Comment: Here is the hole file: http://pastebin.com/RQTfSj8b

Comment: The code in your `site_base.html` file

Comment: My site_base.html: http://pastebin.com/5da0q6mv

Comment: Add `{% load bootstrap3 %}` to child template file after `extends`

Comment: I works. Thank you :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `{% load bootstrap3 %}` to child template file after the `{% extends 'site_base.html' %}`.

Comment: Adding that worked for me, but why? I have `{% load bootstrap3 %}` in my base.html file.

Comment: @joshlsullivan Because this is how template tags work. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14141707/1418794) and the answers for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Did you put it inside `<form>` tags ?

This is how your bootstrap form should look (from django-bootstrap3 github page) like:

```
<form action="/url/to/submit/" method="post" class="form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_form form %}
    {% buttons %}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            {% bootstrap_icon "star" %} Submit
        </button>
    {% endbuttons %}
</form>
```

Comment: yes, i dit.
is there a way tho use django-template-inheritance with this package?

Comment: If i remove the "block" i get: Invalid block tag on line 22: 'bootstrap_form'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Comment: You should also start by putting your {% bootstrap_css %}
{% bootstrap_javascript %} (not sure for {% bootstrap_messages %} ) in the right place, which means inside the <head> next to <link...> and <script...> and probably the call to jquery before the call to javascript bootstrap. if you inspect the elements of the template page in the browser you'll probably notice some incoherence.