# Error during template rendering in django with specific image that displays on other pages

Tags: django

I've been trying to get a Django instance my predecessor here at work left me up and running, and I ran into a strange error with the templates that I can't seem to comprehend. Using the new {% static '/core/images/image_name.gif' %} format to display images works just fine in a header bar for all of the pages - with one specific exception. When I click on that page that causes the error, though, I get told that there's a problem in the *base template*, which all of the other pages that work just fine also extend. It implies that there's a problem with a specific image which displays just fine on all the other pages, and I can't understand why. {% load static %} is performed in every template.

```
Error during template rendering
In template C:\path_to_project\core\templates\core\base.html, error at line 20

401 Client Error: for url: https://bitbucketdev.it.contoso.com/rest/api/1.0/projects?start=0&limit=1000
10      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
11      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
12      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'core/css/style.css' %}">
13    </head> 
14    <body>
15    <div class="container-fluid">
16      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
17        <!-- Brand/logo -->
18        <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://www.contoso.com/us/en/home.html">
19          {% load static %}
20          <img src="{% static '/core/images/contosotransparent.gif' %}" alt="Contoso Technologies" style="width:120px;">
21        </a>
22  
23        <!-- Links -->
24        <ul class="navbar-nav">
25            <li class="nav-item">
26                <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'core:about' %}">About Smart Help Portal</a>
27            </li>
28            <li class="nav-item">
29                <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'core:help' %}">Why Am I Here?</a>
30            </li>
```

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this sort of error? My apologies for not providing more detail - I'm not as familiar with Django as I should be. If there's anything someone could tell me that could give me a hint as to where to look next, that would be greatly appreciated.

Here's a gist with the files - the base.html that both extend, the portal.html that does not work, and the about.html that does work.

https://gist.github.com/wanderso/0846ee0acba1cd6f336f07b18adc30ea

Comment: Usually all `load` includes (`{% load static %}` in this case) is performed at the beginning of the template file so it's easier to read (and [they need to be included in every template](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41895781/10400050)). Anyway, can you provide the full content of the file `path_to_project\core\templates\core\base.html` in your question? And if possible, the template file of the page when this error occurs?

Comment: Is there a way to attach files? I'm not sure that a 70-line and 112-line file is super great to add to a question post.

Comment: Not really, [SO guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) strictly encourages to include the said code in question. But I see the issue, although 70 lines is not too shabby. But if you want to reduce the code, try to (temporarily) exclude the parts that you think is unnecessary from your templates and test if the error still occurs. When you're down to what seems reasonable, include the code. And if you stumble on any part that actually removed the error you can add that too :)

Comment: I added a gist, Johan. Sorry, I didn't want to turn this into a wall of code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing this as an answer since the comment max length weren't enough. Here's the modifications that I suggest, please try the code after each modification (because I've arranged them in probability of cause).

**1. base.html**

Remove the second `{% load static %}` that's on line 20, and keep the one on line 2 (this is what I believe might cause the error).

**2. about.html & portal.html**

Move the `{% load ... %}` tags to the top of the page. The only tag allowed to be before it is the `{% extends ... %}` block (this isn't a strict rule in Django Templates, just something for the moment to eliminate possible interferences).

**3. base.html & portal.html**

Merge the `{% load ... %}` tags into one line. That means, in `portal.html`

```
{% load static %}
{% load portal_extras %}
{% load bootstrap4 %}
          |
          v
{% load static portal_extras bootstrap4 %}
```

And in `base.html`

```
{% load static %}
{% load portal_extras %}
          |
          v
{% load static portal_extras %}
```

**4. All concerned template files**

Search through and make sure that there aren't any double `{% load ... %}` tags that loads the same module twice.

Comment: Sadly, I've tried all of those things, and we're still getting errors. Should I update the gists?

Comment: Unfortunately I am out of suggestions. I can't really comprehend what could cause the error. If you remove the `{% static '/core/images/contosotransparent.gif' %}` altogether, does it work then? Not suggesting it's a solution, just wondering if it crashes because it's something wrong with that specific `static` tag or if it's because it's the first instance of a `static` tag.

Comment: I summoned the departed person who used to run this thing, and she just said that *all* bugs in the program report that they're crashing at /core/images/contosotransparent.gif . She then proceeded to find and fix the bug. I have no idea why this happened this way, but it did.

Comment: I've never heard of that kind of bug before, but glad it's resolved :)