# Static files doesn't load anymore - Django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-staticfiles, django-static

In the beginning everything worked perfectly fine, but now I have a problem where my static files doesn't load. I think this is a very weird problem since I didn't really touch anything that could've had an influence on the problem when it happened. Everything else is working fine, I just can't get the static files for some reason. I sometimes get a 200 http response trying to get the static files like so:

```
    [20/Aug/2020 16:12:51] "GET /order/checkout/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2029
    [20/Aug/2020 16:12:51] "GET /static/my_pizza_place/js/client.js HTTP/1.1" 200 2194
    [20/Aug/2020 16:12:51] "GET /static/css/master.css HTTP/1.1" 200 80
    [20/Aug/2020 16:12:51] "GET /static/css/global.css HTTP/1.1" 200 530
```

But it's still not applying the styling to my html code. I usually just get a 304 http response on my client.js file though. I feel like I have tried almost everything at this point, so I hope you guys can help me figuring out what the problem is.

## My files:

- **SETTINGS.PY**

```
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
```

- **BASE.HTML**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    {% load static %}
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        ...
    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/master.css' %}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/global.css' %}">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="..." crossorigin="anonymous">
        
        <script src="{% static 'my_pizza_place/js/client.js' %}" defer></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container mycontent">
        {% block checkout %}
            
        {% endblock %}
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

- **INDEX.HTML**

```
    {% extends 'base.html' %}
    {% block content %}
        ...
    {% endblock %}
```

- **URLS.PY - IN PROJECT FOLDER**

```
    urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('',views.HomePage.as_view(),name="home"),
        path('customer/',include('customer.urls', namespace='customer')),
        path('customer/',include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
        path('order/',include('orders.urls',namespace='order'))
    ]
```

- **VIEWS.PY**

```
    class HomePage(TemplateView):
        template_name = 'index.html'
```

- **DIRECTORY STRUCTURE**

  > - Project
  >
  > > - app_name
  > > - project_name
  > > - static
  > >
  > > > - css
  > > >
  > > > > - global.css
  > > > > - master.css
  > > >
  > > > - my_pizza_place
  > > >
  > > > > - js
  > > > >
  > > > > > - client.js
  > >
  > > - templates
  > >
  > > > - base.html

If you need any more information please just ask. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show the html with the extends block ?

Comment: @EricMartin I have added some extra files including the index.html file. The html code itself is pretty standard so I didn't add that.

Comment: Thanks, i asked it to check the loadstatic in every template.Same conclusion with @AliReda-M . You can have details in : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14141350/why-load-staticfiles-for-every-template-even-if-it-is-extended/41895781

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is simply that you should add {% load static %} in each file. You don't have to necessarily link the css files in each .html file, but in each file you should load the static files. I have faced this problem before and I am sure this will solve it for you, be sure to add the {% load static %} before the {%block content %} tag. If you need further explanation, comment below.

Comment: That unfortunately didn't work. I have just read the django docs about template inheritence and yes in theory you should also add the load tag in the other html files, since the tags is not inherited by the child template. The weird thing is that it has worked fine for me in other projects where i didn't add an extra load tag. It also worked fine for this project in some time as i've mentioned. I have no idea whats going on here to be honest. But thanks for the response none the less, thats always appreciated.

Comment: welcome, but if you havent tried it, try you'll lose nothing. gd luck!