# Static files doesn't update - Django

Tags: django, firefox, browser, django-rest-framework, django-staticfiles

This is the second time i'm commenting about this problem and I really hope you can help me this time since i've gained some more information about the problem. So the problem is basically that all my Django projects doesn't update the static files (this also includes projects which I have downloaded). So I can fx still see the old styling from the css files but the changes is not displayed. When i insert the css or js directly into the html file i can see it though. I thought that it maybe had something to do with my browsers stored caches but I have tried to do a hard refresh, clearing all my caches, installing whitenoise and forced browser to reload the css file by adding an extra parameter to the end of the src tag. I have also tried `python manage.py collectstatic` and almost everything else on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27911070/django-wont-refresh-staticfiles).

When the problem bagan to occur I was working with the implementation of stripe. I don't neccessarily think that stripe is the problem since the problem occured hours after i had already implementet the checkout site. I just think it's worth at least mentioning.

---

### Some of my venv packages:

Django | 3.0.3

django-bootstrap4 | 2.2.0

stripe | 2.50.0

---

### Weird behaviour:

Yesterday when I decided to comment out the bootstrap link to see if that was somehow the problem, the changes to the css file got applied to the site. I tried to do that several times and that seemed to be the problem but that only worked for like an hour. Now I cant apply any changes to the sites whatsoever.

---

### My first post:

If you want to see my first post about the problem, you can check it out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63509019/static-files-doesnt-load-anymore-django). Keep in mind that the problem is not only happening to my Django projects but also the projects which i've downloaded.

---

I have no idea whats happening and I would very much appreciate your help. If you need any more information please just ask.

---

---

#### Edit:

*I created a new folder and css/js file and it kind of worked. I believe the reason it worked was bcs whenever you create a new css/js file, Django needs to atleast load the content of the file once. But whenever I wanted to make other changes it suddenly didn't work again. In my file i had two links to css files. This should usually not be a problem, but apparently it was for me. I deleted one css link and It suddenly worked fine again. If anyone knows why this happened pls tell me, i'm all ears.*

Answer (score 2):

Assume you did everything correctly! I once faced this problem too and I fixed it by changed the directory name inside static folder to the same name as my app name. `static/css/style.css` change to `static/app_name/style.css`. Also don't forget to refresh the browser (`ctrl + r` or `cmd + r`). Hope this would help.

Comment: Hey Kimhong, thanks for the comment! Your suggestion helped me in the right direction. Look at my edit for more information.

Comment: @Carlos you saved my project's live, man!
thanks!