# Can not get my static style sheet to connect to my html using django

Tags: html, css, django, static

so i am having weird issue with my static css in the newest django. It is only changing to color on my `<h1>` the rest is totally unchanged. The static folder is in the root of the project.
here is my css

```
h1{
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: black;
    margin-left:150px;


}
body{
    background-color: lightblue;

}
.container{
    width:100%;
}
.products{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30%;
}
h5{
    color:red;
}
```

here is the html i am trying to change

```
{%extends "base.html"%}

{%block content%}
<div class="container">

<!-- for loop to render each product -->
{%for product in product_list%}
<!-- <h1>test</h1> -->

    <div class="products">
        <ul>
            <h5>{{product.title}}</h5>

            <li>Price:{{product.price}}</li>
            {% if product.available %}
            <li>In stock</li>
            <li> Amount in Backstock:{{product.quantity}}</li>
            <li>Sell by Date:{{product.date}}</li>

            {%else%}
            <li>Out of Stock</li>
            {% endif %} 
            <a type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"href='/product/{{product.id}}/update'> update </a>
            <a type="button" class="btn btn-danger" href='/product/{{product.id}}/delete'> delete </a>
        </ul>
    </div>
{%endfor%}
</div>

{%endblock%}
```

here is my static and static_dir

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static",
    '/var/www/static/',
]
```

Comment: Where are you including the markup to load the CSS?

Comment: Did you try loading the staticfiles {% load staticfiles %} on the extended html file? If that's the problem you should look to this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14141350/why-load-staticfiles-for-every-template-even-if-it-is-extended/41895781)

Comment: ``` {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">``` here is what i put in the head of my extend still didnt work. When i use `<style> that works

Comment: it works now no idea why but thanks for the help